# Why is NP only a set of decision problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Taken from Wikipedia but all definitions I have seen are similar to this:

> "NP is the set of decision problems where the "yes"-instances can be accepted in polynomial time by a non-deterministic Turing machine."

Why is NP restricted to only decision problems? Is it?

Lets take subset sum as an example:

(type 1) Decision problem - Is there a subset B of A that sums up to k?

(type 2) "Normal" problem - what is the subset B of A that sums up to k?

I write "Normal" on type 2 there because that feels like what you usually do when you solve such a problem.

Am I right in understanding, using the definition of NP, that type 1 is in NP while type 2 is not?

It feels like the definition would work equally well in the way it is sometimes written informally

> "All ***problems*** whose solutions can be checked in polynomial time".

(I found a similar question but it didn't really seem to answer this question)

Comment: very sure that this question would receive better answers at: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Problem 2 is an optimization problem and these can be expressed as decision problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that **NP** is a class of decision problems (problems with a yes-no answer), so problem (1) is in **NP** and problem (2) is not in **NP**. Part of the reason for setting up **NP** this way is historical (formal language theory concerns questions about whether or not strings/natural numbers belong to a particular set), part of it is for mathematical simplicity (because these problems have only yes/no answers, you can talk about a problem as just the set of "yes" instances and perform set-theoretic operations on those sets), and part of it is to make certain definitions much easier to work with (reducibility, for example, is really easy to express from a language perspective).

This isn't to say that more general problems aren't interesting - they absolutely are! The problem of type (2) that you've described might not be in **NP**, but it *is* in a complexity class called **FNP** (function **NP**), which is a natural generalization of **NP** to the case where the job is to find a particular object satisfying criteria that can be checked in polynomial time. There's also a corresponding version of class **P** called **FP**, and there's a corresponding **FP** versus **FNP** problem.

Comment: Are the identities P = NP  and FP = FNP relatated?

Comment: Yep! If you’re careful with how you set up the definitions of FP and FNP, then P = NP if and only if FP = FNP.

Answer (score -1):

A short explanation of what P=NP is:

- A yes or no problem is in P [Polynomial time] if the answer can be
  computed in polynomial time.
- A yes-or-no problem is in NP [Non-deterministic Polynomial time] if a
  yes answer can be verified in polynomial time.

You can read a bit more about P=NP in my short article: https://medium.com/@officialgupta/what-is-p-np-2b0fd7b9bd83

Comment: How is this answer addressing his question in any way whatsoever